# g++ compiles mingw complaints

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I'm having a little problem when trying to compile a very simple test c++ code:

I have a Warrior class when I want to define a copy constructor for test purposes. I declare it in Warrior.h and define it in Warrior.cpp.

When compiling the code with g++ on Ubuntu, it works great, however when trying to compile it on Windows7 Codeblocks (mingw), I get the following message :

> error: definition of implicitly-declared 'Warrior::Warrior(const Warrior&)'|||=== Build failed: 1 error(s)

The code:

Warrior.h

```
    #ifndef WARRIOR_H_INCLUDED
    #define WARRIOR_H_INCLUDED
    #include <string>
    #include "Arme.h"
    #include "Warrior.h"

    class Warrior{
        public:
        Warrior(Warrior const& other);
        std::string getName() const;
        Warrior setName(std::string name);
        int getAge() const;
        Warrior setAge(int age);
        int getLife() const;
        Warrior setLife(int life);
        Arme getArme() const;
        Warrior setArme(Arme& arme);


        void attaquer(Warrior& autreCombattant);
        bool isAlive() const;
        Warrior setIsAlive(bool isAlive);
        Warrior(std::string name, int age);
        ~Warrior();

        private:
        std::string m_name;
        int m_age;
        int m_life;
        bool m_isAlive;
        Arme m_arme;
    };


    #endif // WARRIOR_H_INCLUDED
```

Warrior.cpp

```
    #include "Warrior.h"
    #include "Arme.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;



    Warrior Warrior::setName(string name){
        m_name=name;
        return *this;
    }

    string Warrior::getName() const{
        return m_name;
    }



    int Warrior::getAge() const{
        return m_age;
    }

    Warrior Warrior::setAge(int age){
        m_age=age;
        return *this;
    }

    int Warrior::getLife() const{
        return m_life;
    }

    Warrior Warrior::setLife(int life){
        m_life=life;
        if(life<=0){
            cout << m_name << " est mort." << endl;
        }else{
            cout << m_name << " a la vie suivante : " << m_life << endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Arme Warrior::getArme() const{
        return m_arme;
    }

    Warrior Warrior::setArme(Arme& arme){
        m_arme=arme;
        cout << m_name  << " a maintenant l'arme suivante : " << arme.getName() << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    void Warrior::attaquer(Warrior& autreCombattant){
        autreCombattant.setLife(autreCombattant.getLife() - m_arme.getDegat());
    }

    bool Warrior::isAlive() const{
        return m_isAlive;
    }



    Warrior Warrior::setIsAlive(bool isAlive){
        m_isAlive=isAlive;
        return *this;
    }

    Warrior::Warrior(string name, int age): m_name(name), m_age(age), m_arme("b",4){
        m_life=300;
        cout << name << " vient de rejoindre l'arene" << endl;
    }


    Warrior::~Warrior(){}


    Warrior::Warrior(Warrior const& autre): m_name(autre.getName())
    {}
```

Arme.h

```
    #ifndef ARME_H_INCLUDED
    #define ARME_H_INCLUDED
    #include <string>

    class Arme{
    private:
        int m_degat;
        std::string m_name;
    public:
        int getDegat() const;
        Arme setDegat(int degat);
        std::string getName() const;
        Arme setName(std::string name);
        Arme(std::string name, int degat);
        Arme();

    };

    #endif // ARME_H_INCLUDED
```

Arme.cpp

```
    #include "Arme.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;



    int Arme::getDegat() const{
        return m_degat;
    }

    Arme Arme::setDegat(int degat){
        m_degat=degat;
        return *this;

    }

    string Arme::getName() const{
        return m_name;

    }

    Arme Arme::setName(string name){
        m_name=name;
        return *this;
    }

    Arme::Arme(std::string name, int degat): m_name(name), m_degat(degat){
    }

    Arme::Arme(){
        m_name="default weapon";
        m_degat=1;
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Need more details. As a guess, two alternatives. 1. look for another, wrong `Warrior.h` file existing at Windows and getting found and included instead of the right one (also learn difference of `#include <>` and `#include ""`, it *might* be relevant). 2. Look for preprosessor `#if` sections, which evaluate differently under Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I added the full code. The code is working well when I remove the copy constructor so I suppose that's neither an "include" problem nor a preprocessor one

Comment: You have both `Warrior(Warrior const& other);` and `Warrior(Warrior const& autre);` defined in your class.  Pick one.

Comment: Sorry Retired Ninja that was a copy/paste error, I edited the code, the problem is still here

Comment: And you couldn't reproduce this problem with [less code](http://rootdirectory.de/wiki/MacheteDebugging)?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed my project on codeblocks, then created a new one and I have added the previously created files, now it compiles without any problem.

It seems to me Codeblocks has a kind of cache engine that was not refreshed...weird!